# Unable to debug JavaScript in IntelliJ 2017.3.x

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, intellij-idea2017

I am developing a React app with Jest tests. With IntelliJ 2017.2.x, I could set a break point in a test and click the debug button. When execution reached the break point, it stopped and I could do the usual debugging.

However, IntelliJ 2017.3.x does not stop execution at my breakpoints any more. The Debug Console tab gives the following output:

```
/usr/bin/node --inspect-brk=36941 --require /home/l/bin/idea-IU-173.3727.127/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/helpers/jest-intellij/lib/jest-intellij-stdin-fix.js /home/l/devel/src/redacted --colors --testResultsProcessor /home/l/bin/idea-IU-173.3727.127/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/helpers/jest-intellij/lib/jest-intellij-test-results-processor.js --testPathPattern ^/home/l/devel/src/redacted$ --testNamePattern "^redacted$"
Debugger listening on port 36941.
Warning: This is an experimental feature and could change at any time.
To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
    chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:36941/291944a5-5f9a-4ee7-a5c1-551b5788d496
Debugger attached.
```

Is this a problem with my project or IDE configuration? Or is it a bug in IntelliJ?

Comment: I use another tool `Postman` to debug my JavaScript APIs. Recently, they've been displaying a warning that Chrome is discontinuing Plugins and to download their Native Application. IntelliJ requires a Chrome Plugin, so maybe it has something to do with the IntelliJ Chrome Plugin?

Comment: @Matt I am attempting to debug tests for a React-based UI, not an API. I don't think Postman will be helpful. I have the JetBrains plugin installed in Chrome when I want to debug the app directly. But from my experience I have been able to debug tests without it. Of course, now that I have it installed, there might be some conflict. Additionally, I see from the 2017.3 release notes that JetBrains added more support for debugging React apps, so this might have something to do with the issue I am seeing.

Comment: @Matt I will work on a proper MCVE so I have non-project code which I can share online. Hopefully developing a good example will bring the issue to light.

Comment: Have you check that `File` -> `Settings` -> `Languages & Frameworks` -> `Javascript` -> `JavaScript Language version` is set to `ReactJSX`?

Comment: @Matt Yes it is. Looks like that setting was imported for the project.

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the issue with new sample project? It seems to work fine on my machine. Also please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue.

Comment: @y.bedrov creating a new project is what I mean by MCVE in my possibilities my previous comment.